# Atomic Operation C++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

In C++, Windows platform, I want to execute a set of function calls as atomic so that execution doesn't switches to other threads in my process. How do I go about doing that? Any ideas, hints?

**EDIT:** I have a piece of code like:

```
someObject->Restart();

WaitForSingleObject(handle, INFINITE);
```

Now the **Restart()** function does its work asynchronously, so it returns quickly and when that someObject is restarted it sends me an event from another thread where I signal the event handle on which I'm waiting and thus continue processing. But now the problem is that before the code reaches **WaitForSingleObject()** part, I receive the restart completion event and I signal the event and after that **WaitForSingleObject()** never returns since it is not signaled again. That's why I want to execute both **Restart()** and **WaitForSingleObject()** as atomic.

Comment: The question is: Why do you want to do that? If you are trying to "synchronize" access to data structures by forbidding the kernel to switch threads, you're on a very wrong way of doing things. So please explain why you would want to do that.

Comment: Even if you could do this, it'd break on a multicore system which would execute multiple threads *simultaneously*

Comment: How are you signaling your handle?  `PulseEvent()` or `SetEvent()`?

Comment: I'm signaling with SetEvent()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is generally not possible. You can't force the OS to not switch to other threads.
What you can do is one of the following:

- Use locks, mutexes, criticals sections or semaphores to synchronize a handful of threads that touch the same data.
- Use basic operations that are atomic such as compare-and-exchange or atomic-add in the form of win32 api calls such as `InterlockedIncrement()` and `InterlockedCompareExchange()`

Answer (score 7):

You don't want all threads to wait, you just want to wait for the new thread to be done, without the risk of missing the signal. This can be done using a semaphore.

Create a semaphore known by both this code and the code eventually executed by Restart, using CreateSemaphore(NULL,0,1,NULL).
In the code you've shown, you'll still use WaitforSingleObject to wait for your semaphore. When the thread executing the Release code is done with it's work, have it call ReleaseSemaphore.

If ReleaseSemaphore is called first, WaitforSingleObject will let you pass immediately. If WaitforSingleObject is called first, it will wait for ReleaseSemaphore.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686946(VS.85).aspx) should also help you.

Answer (score 2):

A general solution to lost event race is a counting semaphore.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `PulseEvent()` to signal your handle?  If so, that's the problem.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684914(VS.85).aspx),

> If no threads are waiting, or if no
>   thread can be released immediately,
>   PulseEvent simply sets the event
>   object's state to nonsignaled and
>   returns.

So if the handle is signaled before you wait on it, the handle is placed immediately in the nonsignaled state by `PulseEvent()`.  That would appear to be why your are "missing" the event.  To correct this, replace `PulseEvent()` with `SetEvent()`.

With this scenario, though, you may need to reset the event after the wait is complete.  This of course depends on if this code is executed more than once during the lifetime of your application.  Assuming your waiting thread is the ***only*** thread that is waiting on the handle, use `CreateEvent()` to create an auto reset event.  This will automatically reset the handle after your waiting thread is released, making it automatically available for the next time through.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could suspend (using [SuspendThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686345%28VS.85%29.aspx)) all other threads in the process, but I suppose you should rethink design of your program.

Comment: SuspendThread is considered dodgy behaviour by many people, who think only Debuggers and Garbage Collectors implementations should be suspending threads.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to fix. Just make sure that the event is the auto-reset event (see the parameters of the CreateEvent) and only call SetEvent to the event handle, never call ResetEvent or PulseEvent or some other things. So the WaitForSingleObject will always return properly. If the event has been already set, the WaitForSingleObject will return immediately and reset the event.

Answer (score -1):

Although I worry about your design in general (ie you are making concurrent tasks sequential, thus losing all the benefits of the hard work to make it concurrent), I think I see the simple solution.

Change your event handle to be MANUAL RESET instead of AUTORESET. (see CreateEvent).

Then you won't miss the signal.
After WaitForSingleObject(...), call ResetEvent().

EDIT:
forget what I just said.  That won't work. see comments below.

Comment: This will not fix the problem.  If he is using an auto-reset event already, the event remains signaled until a waiting thread is released.  If there are no waiting threads, the event remains signaled until there is one.  At that point, the thread is immediately released, and the event is reset.  See the MSDN documentation on CreateEvent:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682396(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Oh, your right.  I forgot.
So he must be doing something wrong.  Either some other thread is also waiting on the object, or he's using the broken PulseEvent or something.

Comment: Auto-reset events are very reliable, if you need to notify just one thread. There is no need to change the the auto-reset event to the manual-reset event.